# PHP unit testing protected variables in an abstract class

Tags: php, phpunit

Here is the code I'm trying to unit test:

```
public function getDao () {
    $dao = '';

    if (isset($this->_dao)) {
        $dao = $this->_dao;
    } else {
        $dao = new $this->_daoClassName; 
    }

    return $dao;
}
```

The class is an abstract class, and `$_daoClassName` is a protected variable. Each concrete class sets a value for `$_daoClassName`

How can I unit test this code? I'm trying to use PHPUnit's  $this->getMockForAbstractClass() but I don't think I can override the protected method. Alternatively, is there a better pattern I should be using on this getDao() method?

Comment: Create a dummy class that extends yours and defines `_daoClassName` with an expected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend a function like:

```
abstract protected function getDaoClassName();
```

Which should be implement by sub classes. (enforced through `abstract`)

Then you can configure your mock in a way that the function returns a certain value:

```
$stub = $this->getMockForAbstractClass('YourClass');
$stub->expects($this->any())
     ->method('getDaoClassName')
     ->will($this->returnValue('SomeDaoClass'));
```

And then test the method:

```
$dao = $stub->getDao();
$this->assertEquals('SomeDaoClass', get_class($dao));
```